# is it possible to create a payment profile and a customer profile, using api, but in compliance with the pci compliance regulations?

Tags: authorize.net, pci-compliance

I am working on my platform, where we already use the functionality provided by sdk-php, so that my client can make payments on our platform through Authorize, using the embedded iframe.

Now, my client requests to generate a payment profile and customer profile without having to perform a transaction, but I noticed in your documentation that only allow to create customer profiles with the card number available, ie, that should be sent by api, so it would not be complying with the pci compliance regulations.

Please, could you tell me if you have any alternative?

I look forward to your comments.

I looked at the documentation, and only the creation of the customer profile is available, but setting the card data:
https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-create-customer-profile